# How do I get a Custom Post Type single to show on a sub level page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a custom website structure where we will have a top level site, the brand ( www.domain.com ) and then will have sub level sites, location ( www.domain.com/region/city/locale/location ).

I have created a custom post type "events". On each of these sub level sites is a page "events" (www.domain.com/region/city/locale/location/events) that has the template set to a custom template that brings in a list of events for that location.

**The problem** I am having is when I click onto an individual event it takes me to www.domain.com/events/the-event.  I would like it to keep me on my sub level site at www.domain/region/city/locale/location/events/the-event.

register post type:

```
args  = array(
    'labels'               => $labels,
    'public'               => true,
    'has_archive'          => false,
    'hierarchical'         => true,
    'publicly_queryable'   => true,
    'query_var'            => true,
    'rewrite'              => array(
         'slug' => 'events'
    ),
```

Now I know there are issues with having a CPT named the same as a post type. So it is possible something needs to be adjusted there.  But I can not get it to recognize that the sub level site is a single template for the event.

All help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

1. region/city/locale/location are pages.
2. the events and the sub level pages are connected via custom meta 'location_id'.

Comment: _“when I click onto an individual event it takes me to www.domain.com/events/the-event”_ - that matches the slug you defined for the CPT. _“I would like it to keep me on my sub level site at www.domain/region/city/locale/location/events/the-event.”_ - based on _what_? How exactly is your event connected to `region/city/locale/location`? Does that connection even actually exist so far?

Comment: /region/city/locale/location/ are categories? Tags? Pages?

Comment: Updated my post to answer these questions.  region/city/locale/location are pages.  And the post type is connected to them by sharing the same value in a custom meta 'location_id'.